# How to disable virtualenv at Travis CI?

Tags: python, virtualenv, travis-ci

I have a Python project with which I am using zc.buildout and pyenv. Travis seems to automatically activate a virtualenv for my project and I can't find any documentation to disable it.

Is there a good way to disable virtualenv in Travis CI?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why? What package has problems being installed in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 4):

Choose a different language which sidesteps Python setup. For example, `language: generic`.

You would be responsible for doing most other stuff, but that might work for you.

Answer (score 2):

ftr: Since travis decided to [remove python 3.7 from the default VMs](https://travis-ci.community/t/pyenv-global-3-7-now-fails-on-xenial-it-was-working-3-days-ago/9430), I had the same use-case for a project which required python 3.7. The solution is to use the python language and to deactivate the virtualenv. Optionally the python interpreter can be set with pyenv also.

```yaml
language: python

python:
  - "3.7"
install:
  # deactivate the virtual environment, which is activated by travis
  - deactivate
  # use pyenv to switch python
  - pyenv global 3.7.1
```